# Was Daenerys' Last Confrontation with Drogo magic or an illusion?

Tags: game-of-thrones

During the season 2 finale of GoT we saw Daenerys go through a series of illusions in the House of the Undying. Was this event, in fact, an illusion or actual magic?

As Khal Drogo said, "These questions are meant for men with skinny arms."

Comment: Did you say "illusion" but mean "hallucination"? Because in my book, "illusion" *is* magic.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Pyat Pree admits to Dannerys that the magical powers of the House of the Undying have started to return after her dragons were born:

> "When your dragons were born, our magic was born again."

The whole reason for Pyat Pree to lure Dannerys into the House of the Undying is for the warlocks to acquire the dragons. To do that, the warlocks used their newly returned powers to create illusions to entice her to stay. I very much doubt that it was the actual Khal Drogo returned to life. The only magical power to have successfully return people from the dead (the priests of R'hllor) are only successful up to a point and at great cost.

Answer (score 4):

Magic. Pyat Pree is a warlock, warlocks are known to practice magic.

Comment: Those whom practice magic actually practice illusions. "A magician performs illusions, tricks are done by..."

Comment: "Magical illusion"?

Comment: @MathiasOse A magical illusion is still an illusion.

Comment: @Mariovingian Wouldn't a magical illusion still be magic as well?

Comment: @batpigandme "No."  Magic is supernatural and an illusion is not.

Comment: To be particular, *Conjurers*  perform illusions (e.g. fake "magic" through slight-of-hand, etc...), Magicians actually perform real magic (whatever that may be). That's not using in-book parlance, though.

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V-cedOBqigw

Comment: Regardless of this lovely discussion about magic vs illusions, the implication is that the warlocks from the House of the Undying do practice real magic.